# if statement to determine steady-state

Tags: fortran

My code below correctly solves a 1D heat equation for a function u(x,t).  I now want to find the steady-state solution, the solution that no longer changes in time so it should satisfy u(t+1)-u(t) = 0.  What is the most efficient way to find the steady-state solution?  I show three different attempts below, but I'm not sure if either are actually doing what I want.  The first and third have correct syntax, the second method has a syntax error due to the if statement. Each method is different due to the change in the if structure.

Method 1 :

```
program parabolic1
  integer, parameter :: n = 10, m = 20 
  real, parameter :: h = 0.1, k = 0.005 !step sizes
  real, dimension (0:n) :: u,v
  integer:: i,j
  real::pi,pi2
  
  u(0) = 0.0; v(0) = 0.0; u(n) = 0.0; v(n) =0.0
  pi = 4.0*atan(1.0)    
  pi2 = pi*pi 
  
  do i=1, n-1
     u(i) = sin( pi*real(i)*h)
  end do
  
  do j = 1,m 

    do i = 1, n-1
       v(i) = 0.5*(u(i-1)+u(i+1))
    end do 
    t = real(j)*k  !increment in time, now check for steady-state

    !steady-state check: this checks the solutions at every space point  which I don't think is correct.
    do i = 1,n-1
       if ( v(i) - u(i) .LT. 1.0e-7 ) then
       print*, 'steady-state condition reached'
       exit 
       end if
    end do

    do i = 1, n-1 !updating solution
       u(i) = v(i)       
    end do 

  end do 
end program parabolic1
```

Method 2 :

```
program parabolic1
  integer, parameter :: n = 10, m = 20 
  real, parameter :: h = 0.1, k = 0.005 !step sizes
  real, dimension (0:n) :: u,v
  integer:: i,j
  real::pi,pi2
  
  u(0) = 0.0; v(0) = 0.0; u(n) = 0.0; v(n) =0.0
  pi = 4.0*atan(1.0)    
  pi2 = pi*pi 
  
  do i=1, n-1
     u(i) = sin( pi*real(i)*h)
  end do
  
  do j = 1,m 

    do i = 1, n-1
       v(i) = 0.5*(u(i-1)+u(i+1))
    end do 
    t = real(j)*k  !increment in time, now check for steady-state

    !steady-state check: (This gives an error message since the if statement doesn't have a logical scalar expression, but I want to compare the full arrays v and u as shown.
       if ( v - u .LT. 1.0e-7 ) then
       print*, 'steady-state condition reached'
       exit 
       end if

    do i = 1, n-1 !updating solution
       u(i) = v(i)       
    end do 

  end do 
end program parabolic1
```

Method 3 :

```
program parabolic1
  integer, parameter :: n = 10, m = 20 
  real, parameter :: h = 0.1, k = 0.005 !step sizes
  real, dimension (0:n) :: u,v
  integer:: i,j
  real::pi,pi2
  
  u(0) = 0.0; v(0) = 0.0; u(n) = 0.0; v(n) =0.0
  pi = 4.0*atan(1.0)    
  pi2 = pi*pi 
  
  do i=1, n-1
     u(i) = sin( pi*real(i)*h)
  end do
  
  do j = 1,m 

    do i = 1, n-1
       v(i) = 0.5*(u(i-1)+u(i+1))
    end do 
    t = real(j)*k  !increment in time, now check for steady-state

    !steady-state check: Perhaps this is the correct expression I want to use
       if( norm2(v) - norm2(u) .LT. 1.0e-7 ) then
       print*, 'steady-state condition reached'
       exit 
       end if

    do i = 1, n-1 !updating solution
       u(i) = v(i)       
    end do 

  end do 
end program parabolic1
```

Comment: What _in words_ do you want the termination condition to be? If you can say that, we can convert that to Fortran. You have two different working conditions ("any point close", "close in norm") that are mathematically different things.

Comment: I want the termination condition to be : the time at which the updated solution u, and the previous solution v, are no longer changing in time.   In other words, I want the code to terminate when the solution at time step t+1 and the solution at time step t, are well below some small tolerance, say 1e-7.  Thus, they're no longer changing in time and the steady-state is reached. Is that clear? Thanks.  In your language, I want to use "any point close", not 
"close in norm".  Sorry, I guess my 3rd method is not mathematically what I want.

Comment: Two vectors can have the same L2 norm and be nothing like each other, so `norm2(u)-norm2(v)` can't be right - do you mean `norm2(u-v)`?

Comment: @francescalus I think I do not understand the norm2...  Thanks for pointing that out. 
 You're right, perhaps I want norm2(u-v).  Is norm2(u-v) a good way to check for the steady-state solution?  Should I use norm2(u-v) or should I use a condition that checks for (u-v) < 1.0e-7?  Which is better for the steady-state check?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: With the correction to method 1 (to say all points close rather than any point close), you seem to be asking "should I use l-2 or l-infinity norm to determine closeness?". That's not really a programming question, but if you are asking "does method 1 work?", there are things to say.

Comment: Yes, I want to say all points close, NOT any point close.  I want the total solution u, and v, to be close, not just close at random space points.  Does method 1 work?  I want to determine closeness like I do in method 1, except, I want it to be for all points. Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without discussing which method to determine "closeness" is best or correct (not really being a programming problem) we can focus on what the Fortran parts of the methods are doing.

Method 1 and Method 2 are similar ideas (but broken in their execution), while Method 3 is different (and broken in another way).

Note also that in general one wants to compare the magnitude of the difference `abs(v-u)` rather than the (signed) difference `v-u`. With non-monotonic changes over iterations these are quite different.

Method 3 uses `norm2(v) - norm2(u)` to test whether the arrays `u` and `v` are similar. This isn't correct. Consider

```
norm2([1.,0.])-norm2([0.,1.])
```

instead of the more correct

```
norm2([1.,0.]-[0.,1.])
```

Method 2's

```
if ( v - u .LT. 1.0e-7 ) then
```

has the problem of being an invalid array expression, but the "are all points close?" can be written appropriately as

```
if ( ALL( v - u .LT. 1.0e-7 )) then
```

(You'll find other questions around here about such array reductions).

Method 1 tries something similar, but incorrectly:

```
    do i = 1,n-1
       if ( v(i) - u(i) .LT. 1.0e-7 ) then
       print*, 'steady-state condition reached'
       exit 
       end if
    end do
```

This is incorrect in one big way, and one subtle way.

First, the loop is exited when the condition tests true the first time, with a message saying the steady state is reached. This is incorrect: you need *all* values close, while this is testing for *any* value close.

Second, when the condition is met, you `exit`. But you don't `exit` the time iteration loop, you exit the closeness testing loop. (`exit` without a construct name leaves the innermost do construct). You'll be in exactly the same situation, running again immediately after this innermost construct whether the tested condition is ever or never met (if ever met you'll get the message also). You will need to use a construct name on the time loop.

I won't show how to do that (again there are other questions here about that), because you also need to fix the test condition, by which point you'll be better off using `if(all(...` (corrected Method 2) without that additional do construct.

For Methods 1 and 2 you'll have something like:

```
if (all(v-u .lt 1e-7)) then
  print *, "Converged"
  exit
end if
```

And for Method 3:

```
if (norm2(v-u) .lt. 1e-7) then
  print *, "Converged"
  exit
end if
```

Comment: How can I print out the command ALL(u - v) ?   I would like to see how close this difference is becoming at each time step.  I notice, you changed it to ALL (u - v .LT. 1.0e-7) - but that's not something I can actually print out.  Thank you very much for your excellent detailed solution indicating the problem with each method!  If I try to print out ALL(u-v), I get the error message : mask argument of all intrinsic must be a logical array.

Comment: `u-v` is an array which each element like `u(i)-v(i)` and `u-v.lt.1e-7` is a logical array element true/false depending on whether the difference is smaller than that number. `all(L)` is true iff all elements of `L` are true. If you want the maximum value of `u-v` to see how "close" then `maxval(u-v)`.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer and this comment on maxval, this is excellent and very clear.